# Pythonで print(train.describe()) で、データの情報を見たい

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

Pythonでtrain = pd.read_csv('train.tsv', sep = '\t')で
ファイル内のデータを読み込み、print(train.describe()) で、
データの情報を見たいのですが、object型のデータの情報が見れないので、
見れるようにする方法を教えて下さい。int型のデータは見れます。

Comment: [pandas.DataFrame.describe](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html#pandas-dataframe-describe) によれば `include='all'` を指定すると良さそうです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。表示できたのですが見たい平均値がNaNになってしまいました。
数字で表示する方法が分かれば教えて下さい。

Comment: 例えば、対象の列名が `object` だとすると、`df['object'].astype(float).describe()` などとしますが、`NaN` や空欄が含まれているとエラーになるでしょう。その場合は、`df['object'].replace('', np.nan).dropna().astype(float).describe()` としますが、これでもエラーになるかもしれません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。df['object'].astype(float).describe()でいけました。